What type of ADC is this?

What type of ADC is this, and where should I place a probe to see the graph?

It's not a real ADC hence its type is irrelevant.

"where should I place a probe to see the graph" Which graph?

It is a simulated 8-bit ADC. It doesn't need to be a direct equivalent of any real chip. I imagine that the simulation uses the REF+ and REF- inputs to scale the VIN down to an 8-bit value that goes on the output.
Since this ADC has an EOC output, it seems to be a successive approximation type, although it's hard to say. It would need to be a self-clocked SAR type, since it doesn't have an independent approximator clock input.
Flash ADCs don't need an EOC output normally since they have a fixed latency from SOC to the output being valid. Latching a valid output can be done using the conversion clock (SOC).
The edge chosen to latch the data from a flash ADC depends on how close the sample rate is to the maximum supported by the ADC. For sampling below half of the maximum rate, a 1/2 cycle delay is OK to latch the output. For faster sampling, a 1 cycle delay is needed, unless a finer-grained delay is available - usually from subdividing a faster clock.

I'm not entirely confident in the circuit I uploaded above, and I'm having trouble finding a basic SAR ADC circuit to simulate in Multisim. Unfortunately, I also don't have the resources to build one at the moment. I'm specifically looking for an ADC circuit with digital outputs (aside from a flash ADC). If you have any suggestions, I would be truly grateful for your assistance!

@25thbam Multisim has documentation, I hope, for the component models they supply. You should be able to read how to use their ADC component. There should ideally be an example circuit for most components included with Multisim. That's how it is with most SPICE systems - after all, the developers themselves had to check that it works, so they set up a schematic anyway. May as well give it to customers :)

@25thbam I have no idea what you are actually trying to do. Do you want to learn about ADCs by simulating them? Is this a homework project for school? I'm sure if you search for Multisim ADC examples - either online or in the installation directory of Multisim on your computer - you will find some for sure.
